# discord bot - send multiple variables from user

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to let user send multiple variables to the bot. types are string, uint.

So in the end, user needs to send 'hello world` and 5.

Is the only way that user sends one string and i should be doing the split in the bot code ? such as user sends `hello world&5` and then in bot code, I do `msg.content.split('&')`.

Am I on the right path or is there a better way ?

Comment: Which language are you using? You've tagged py, js and c#, also have you tested your idea or what exactly is your question

Comment: Don't spam tags please. Next time.

Comment: In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184220/discord-bot-send-multiple-variables-from-user#comment124066914_70184300) you mentioned that you're looking for answers using `discord.js` so I removed other tags. With almost 5k reps you should know how to tag questions correctly though.

Answer (score 4):

This is another way to do it:

```
@bot.command()
async def send_message(ctx, *args):
    print(args)
```

Then users will be able to write for example `"hello world" "test 123" test 5` and **discord.py** will split the input.

Comment: could you bring an example in js (from discord.js ? )

Comment: No, sorry. I know how to do it only in discord.py.

Comment: You added `discord.py` tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use JavaScript and discord.js; yes, you are on the right path. Next, you just need to trim the string if users pass spaces around the `&`.